# TSC Payload is either malformed or incomplete

Tags: python, rest, api, tableau-api

I am using TableauServerClient to update the owner of a report on Tableau server. Here is my simple code:

```
Try:
                single_workbook = server.workbooks.get_by_id(workbook_id)       #default ownerid of fsg_tableaureporting
                single_workbook.owner_id = ownerid

                if (server.workbooks.update(single_workbook)):
                    print('Workbook owner has been updated successfully')

                else:
                    print('Workbook owner could not be updated. Please try again. Exiting..')

            except Exception as e:
                print('Exceptions occured while changing the owner.')
                print(e)
```

I get the exception at the statement server.workbooks.update(single_workbook).
Anyone have any suggestions?

Python: 3.7.3
TSC: 0.8.1
Tableau server: 2019.1.3 (20191.19.0417.1429) 64-bit Windows

Comment: Are you authenticated? What is the message/code in the exception? Does the new owner have access to the site or project containing the workbook?

Comment: Yes, I can authenticate successfully. New user has access to the server/project. I tried different users but no luck. Exception says "400000: Bad request. Payload is either malformed or incomplete"

Comment: Can you save it without making changes? Are you able to read fields from it after getting it, to make sure it was retrieved properly?

Comment: Even this simple code is failing: `single_workbook = server.workbooks.get_by_id(workbook_id)
                server.workbooks.update(single_workbook)` It is failing with same error "tableauserverclient.server.endpoint.exceptions.ServerResponseError: 400000: Bad Request Payload is either malformed or incomplete"

Comment: What does ``print(single_workbook.name)`` show if you put it right before the update() call?

Comment: Shows the name of the workbook retrieved

Comment: any help anyone :(

Comment: I would suggest you to check logs from /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/logs/vizportal/vizportal_node1-0.log it happened to me that API we returning a general error and inside the log I was able to retrieve the full error

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue. Looking at logs (C:\Tableau Server\data\tabsvc\logs\vizportal\vizportal-0.log for Windows), I see the error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 238; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"dataAccelerationConfig"). Expected elements are <{}owner>,<{}site>,<{}project>,<{}connections>,<{}connectionCredentials>,<{}views>,<{}tags>
```

The error specifically happens at generating the XML here:
https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/188be71e0fbe9d87ac36628af21d2f63af32d020/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/workbooks_endpoint.py#L103

Upon checking whats happening in that request, I see its adding a section in xml for data_acceleration_config which I think is a new feature starting in very recent versions, 2019.4 maybe:
https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/188be71e0fbe9d87ac36628af21d2f63af32d020/tableauserverclient/server/request_factory.py#L485

Unfortunately the API doesnt handle this properly, yet! I am trying to tweak my code to not generate that xml element; will update again if I get to a solution.

Comment: just tried the update on our tableau server 2020.2.. works like a charm! so i guess i ll just leave it and wait for our tableau server to get upgraded :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using tableauserverclient version 0.12 and have face the similar issues; However when I downgrade to version 0.10, I didn't encounter this issue when update workbook project.